# date format from mysql database

Tags: php, date

I have a column type `DATE` in mysql database and want to get date in format like this - `21-jan`.

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT id, date, title, category FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC');
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $date = strtotime($row['date']);
    $date = date_format($date, "d-M"); // line 49
```

Warning:
`date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, integer given... on line 49`

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
$date = strtolower(date("d-M", $date));
```

Take a look at date function: 
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php

Comment: It works, but can I have `21-jan` instead of `21-Jan` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function instead of date_format:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT id, date, title, category FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC');
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $date = date("d-M", strtotime($row['date']));
    $formatedDate = strtolower($date);
```

Comment: It works, but can I have `21-jan` instead of `21-Jan` ?

Comment: @bonaca unfortunately date() function doesn't do that but you can accomplish it with help of strtolower() function

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved.